# multilanguage site

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multi language drupal site. It's in English, German and Japanese. When using a translation, the sites name is still displayed in English. How do I make the site change the site name to the selected language. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't use google before posting this question -> http://groups.drupal.org/node/27712 (5 sec of searching)

Comment: you need i18n module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Drupal, site name and slogan are variables. And there is Variable translation module (in [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) pack) for them.
[image]
More info from Gábor Hojtsy: [Drupal 7's new multilingual systems (part 5) - Site settings](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2011-feb-25/drupal-7039s-new-multilingual-systems-part-5-site-settings)